# LINQ query using list of objects property of an object

Tags: c#, linq

I've tried to decipher how to do this myself but my understanding of LINQ usage is pretty limited.  What I have is two classes as such:

```
public class Grocery
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public List<ItemType> ItemTypes { get; set; }
}

public class ItemType
{
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public long Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

The idea being you can have a `Grocery` object with `ItemName` "Carrots", and that comes in two different `ItemTypes`, e.g. where Weight = 1lb and where Weight = 2lb, with different quantities of each.  Obviously there will be many more items than just carrots, and these are stored in a list also:

```
List<Grocery> groceries;
```

What I'd like to do is get a list of all quantities for all groceries, given a certain weight.  E.g. I could do it like this for all items that have a 1lb type:

```
List<long> quantities = new List<long>();

foreach (Grocery grocery in groceries)
{
    foreach (ItemType itemType in grocery.ItemTypes)
    {
        if (itemType.Weight == 1)
        {
            quantities.Add(itemType.Quantity);
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is how I can achieve the same result using a LINQ expression, though I'm not sure if this is possible without reverting to using `.ForEach` and simply doing the same as the code above but in a less verbose (and therefore less readable) way.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Reno says, `SelectMany` is the way to go. But rather than using `ForEach` to populate a list, go LINQ all the way:

```
List<long> quantities = groceries.SelectMany(g => g.ItemTypes)
    .Where(t => t.Weight == 1)
    .Select(t => t.Quantity)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx). In order to replicate your `foreach` processing, you can use the following:

```
List<long> quantities = groceries.SelectMany(x => x.ItemTypes)
    .Where(x => x.Weight == 1)
    .Select(x => x.Quantity)
    .ToList();
```

In order to get a list of quantities for each Grocery, as you mention in your question, you can use something like this:

```
var groceryQuantities = groceries.Select(g => new
{
    g.ItemName,
    Quantities = g.ItemTypes
        .Where(it => it.Weight == 1)
        .Select(it => it.Quantity)
        .ToList()
}).ToList();
```

This will create a list of anonymous objects, that looks something like this (in JSON for demonstration):

```json
[
    {
        "ItemName": "Grocery #1",
        "Quantities": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    ...
]
```

You can sum the quantities, if that's what you're actually after. That would look like this:

```
var groceryQuantities = groceries.Select(g => new
{
    g.ItemName,
    TotalQuantity = g.ItemTypes
        .Where(it => it.Weight == 1)
        .Sum(it => it.Quantity)
}).ToList();
```

There's a tonne of other things you can do, but this should cover one way to approach this as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

SelectMany is your friend:

```
 groceries.SelectMany(g => g.ItemTypes).Where(t => t.Weight == 1).ToList().ForEach(t => quantities.Add(t.Quantity));
```